# Django AMQP error

Tags: django, amqp

I have a Django application installed that sends off tasks to Celery, and have the following in my `settings.py` file:

```
BROKER_HOST = "localhost"
BROKER_PORT = 5672
BROKER_USER = "user"
BROKER_PASSWORD = "password"
BROKER_VHOST = "host"
BROKER_BACKEND = "amqp"
...
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False
```

I run the server and everything seems fine until I actually go to run the task.  I get the following error:

```
Exception Type:     KeyError
Exception Value:   'No such transport: amqp'
```

I have the AMQP library installed and is listed in my site-packages directory, but I cannot find anything about this error...?

Answer (score 1):

Problem with kombu

> pip install celery kombu==2.4.0

[Celery Error 'No such transport: amqp'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115692/celery-error-no-such-transport-amqp)